# Google Maps labels in German

Tags: maps

I would like the labels of the Google maps that I have on the site to be in German. Although I have inserted language = de, the labels are still in the language of the country where I am. How can I change this? I have pasted the code bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
                    <iframe class="map" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
                            src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1128.3045106380598!2d14.307387666212339!3d46.627494951268254!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x477073627dfe541d%3A0x504b1e7483f2a53b!2sSt.+Veiter+Str.+7%2C+9020+Innere+Stadt%2C+Austria!5e0!3m2!1spl!2spl!4v1484087603660&language=de"
                            allowfullscreen></iframe>
```